# The inefficiency of the all call

Tags: discussion, community

Does anyone see Stack Overflow as wasteful of people's time?
How do we make it less wasteful?

http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2010/04/the-inefficiency-of-the-all-call.html

> "You interrupt 100 people to reach one, or you get ten offers of help (or someone to buy your hockey tickets) when one was all you needed."
>
> "I'm looking for this tool. Anyone know where to find it?" 300,000 people see it, 230 tell you the answer, but of course 229 of those contributions are wasted.

Comment: "New post from any famous IT blog" + "stackoverflow" = "a new discussion on meta each time", obviously.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Seth Godin has nothing to do with IT. He's a marketing guy.

Comment: @mmyers - my bad. I assumed that wrongly after seeing this name repeatedly on HN.

Comment: Non-sequitur alert: The link provided isn't remotely connected to the question.

Comment: If this is a poor question that merits a -9 downvote, why do the answers merit up to +7 upvotes?  Without the question there wouldn't have been the answers.

Answer (score 11):

If SO is acting as an "all call" for you, then that's *your* fault. SO doesn't broadcast over a PA system. SO doesn't IM you. SO doesn't even email you, unless you ask for it, on a specific question, and *even then* it takes its sweet time in doing so.

If you're sitting on SO hitting refresh every 5 seconds and find that new questions are wasting your time... *Then stop reading new questions and go do something else.*

Answer (score 4):

They don't force people to watch StackOverflow *(yet)*.

People who come on it to answer questions have a will to hear/read questions, to provide answers to them. As such, it's not a waste of time, because that's exactly what they meant to do.

Also, with tags and votes, people have a way to filter information to go to what interest them.

Comment: Maybe not Stack Overflow, but I think every programmer should be forced to read TDWTF.

Comment: @Randolpho - I think every programmer is already forced to, during work time.

Answer (score 4):

Searching before you ask a question makes it much less wasteful of people's time.  There are somewhere near half a million answered questions on Stack Overflow.  Most of the time I search Google or SO, I find what I'm looking for before asking.

Answer (score 3):

Who do you suggest is being "interrupted"?

Evey single person who reads your post, or even just the title *asked* to see it. Or rather they asked to see Stack Overflow content.

To keep Stack Overflow efficient we do what we've been doing: close the duplicates and the junk.

Answer (score 2):

It's not inefficient for the one doing the calling. It's probably *maximally efficient* for them since they get answers so quickly, and *that's* really the point of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow et al have saved me (subjectively estimated) about 3-5 times what I have put into them.